# How to make a String into a new one with only lowercase letters (no spaces, apostrophes) using a loop

Tags: java

I need a way to turn sentences into just a String of lowercase letters, i.e. no spaces, apostrophes or anything while using a loop.

```
static String toAlphaLowerCase( String s )
    {
        String c;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
            c = s.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isLetter())
                               return c.toLowerCase();

    }
```

Comment: HINT: either the `+` operator or a `StringBuilder`

Comment: Why don't you use `replaceAll` of `String` https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall

Answer (score 1):

Simple: read about the StringBuilder class. You create an instance of that class before your loop. Then during that loop you add all characters you want to be in your result.
Finally, you call toString() on that builder object and return the result of that call.

Right now you are stopping (returning) after the first letter, and that simply skips all following content.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `StringBuilder` when concatenating the output. `String.charAt(int)` returns a `char`, so you will need a `char` to use that. And `Character.isLetter(char)` **takes** a `char`. Use braces, because omitting them makes the code harder to reason about (and leads to defects such as your code has). Something like,

```
static String toAlphaLowerCase(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**or** use `String.toCharArray()` and iterate the input with a `for-each` loop. Like,

```
static String toAlphaLowerCase(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**or** use a regular expression, like

```
static String toAlphaLowerCase(String s) {
    return s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
}
```

Comment: I explicitly decided to not do all his homework for him, but looks like he found someone to just do that...